# Rails Skip nil objects while looping over a recordset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi I was wondering if someone could show me a more elegant way of doing the below.

I have a record-set, where a nested value may or may not be included and I am struggling to display the information while looping through on the null occurrences, receiving the doesn't exist for nil error.

I know I can fix it by checking first, just wonder if there should be a cleaner way that I'm not aware of.

Current code: (Child may or may not be included)

```
@bookings.each do |booking|
  <tr>
    <td><%= booking.name %></td>
    <td><%= booking.parent.name %></td>
    <td><%= booking.child.name %></td>
  </tr>
```

Potential workaround.

```
@bookings.each do |booking|
  <tr>
    <td><%= booking.name %></td>
    <td><%= booking.parent.name %></td>
  <% if !booking.child_id.nil? %>
    <td><%= booking.child.name %></td>
  <% end %>
  </tr>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The workaround above breaks a table layout (the amount of table data cells should be the same in each row, or kinda `colspan` should be involved.). One might use standard rails approach with [`#try`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/NilClass.html#method-i-try):

```
@bookings.each do |booking|
  <tr>
    <td><%= booking.name %></td>
    <td><%= booking.parent.name %></td>
    <td><%= booking.child.try(:name) %></td>
  </tr>
```

Another way would be to print something more descriptive when there are no children found:

```
@bookings.each do |booking|
  <tr>
    <td><%= booking.name %></td>
    <td><%= booking.parent.name %></td>
    <td><%= booking.child && booking.child.name || 'N/A' %></td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: In your first solution, what if a `child` object is not present against `booking`?

Comment: @titan `booking.child` returns `nil` and `try` on `child` returns `nil` as well.

Comment: Oh right! my bad, error occurs when `name` is called with `nil`. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Ruby2.3, you can use `the safe navigation operator` `&.` for more elegant.

```
@bookings.each do |booking|
  <tr>
    <td><%= booking.name %></td>
    <td><%= booking.parent.name %></td>
    <td><%= booking.child&.name %></td>
  </tr>
```

see: http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/

Answer (score 1):

You should read about ruby `.try()`. In your case, this should work

```
<% @bookings.each do |booking| %>
    <tr>
       <td><%= booking.name %></td>
       <td><%= booking.parent.name %></td>
       <td><%= booking.child.try(:name) %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

As an alternative you can use Rescue

```
<%= booking.child.name rescue nil %>
```

Comment: `try`ing `:child` is senseless, if `booking` is `nil`, it will raise an error two lines above.

Comment: @Stewart explicitly mentioned `:child` may or may not be included thats why he needs to `try` `:child`

Comment: @Stewart `try` invokes the public method whose name goes as first argument just like public_send does, except that if the receiver does not respond to it the call returns nil rather than raising an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Use NullObject pattern, to prevent duplication in future.
Something like this.

```
class Booking
  def child
    super || NullChild.new
  end
end

class NullChild
  def name
  end
end
```